# How To Create an Anchor In a List Item in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I want to create nested tags like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I add a `BulletedList` control in the page:

```
<asp:BulletedList runat="server" CssClass="ad-thumb-list" ID="ImageItem">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Then I add the `ListItem` in the code :

```
    DataTable dt = queryDb(xx);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
        hl.NavigateUrl = string.Format("../stream.aspx?type=={0}",dr["type"]);

        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        //here how to add the `hl` to `li`
        ImageItem.Items.Add(li);
    }
```

In the above code,I have no idea to add the `a` tag to `li`.

I want to use something like this:

```
li.Controls.Add(hl);
```

But it seems taht this is impossible.

What is the problem?

Comment: I think BulletedList is a text-only control. Does not recognise HTML. You can try the `asp:DataList` instead if you don't need the bullets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `DisplayMode` has `Hyperlink` (`BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink`)

```
    ImageItem.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem("PLACE-THE-LINK-TEXT", string.Format("../stream.aspx?type=={0}",dr["type"]));
        //here how to add the `hl` to `li`
        ImageItem.Items.Add(li);
    }
```

Comment: This works. However how about if I want to add a `img` tag inside the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:  [DisplayMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.displaymode.aspx)

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("MicroSoft", "http://www.microsoft.com");
ListItem item1 = new ListItem("Google", "http://www.google.com");
BulletedList1.Items.Add(item);
BulletedList1.Items.Add(item1);
```

Answer (score 0):

ListItem is not a container hence does not provide controls to be added. Use **ListViewDataItem** instead.